# Force Play to JSON serialize timestamps as strings, not integer seconds

Tags: scala, playframework, jackson

I'm trying to figure out how to get Play's toJSon method to serialize java.sql.Timestamp/java.sql.Date objects as date/time strings rather than seconds since epoch, which seems to be the default. I've tried two methods to accomplish this:

1) I changed the Jackson JSON configuration default as seen [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling) in the Global onStart handler:

```
import play.api._
import play.libs.Json

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: play.api.Application){
    println("really started")
    var om = new ObjectMapper()
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
    Json.setObjectMapper(om)
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect. I can tell the code is executing based on the println statement but the serialization is unaffected.

2) Write a custom Writer for the java.sql.Date object:

```
implicit val sqlDateWrites: Writes[java.sql.Date] = new Writes[java.sql.Date] {
   def writes(d: java.sql.Date): JsValue = JsString("WTF")
}
```

However this doesn't work either. I'm not sure if it's an error in how I'm writing it, or if I am just including it in the wrong place (I'm declaring it in the same file that I'm calling "toJson" in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/fancellu/f4b72e853766acf26bf16a7fb37cb8ac

Give this code a go, stores as ISO-8601 format

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up Play's Java JSON library and its Scala library.

If you're using Scala, only use `play.api.libs.json`.  If you're in Java, `play.libs.Json`.

To create a `Writes[java.sql.Date]`, call `Writes.sqlDateWrites(pattern)` with whatever pattern you're using.

`val sqlDateWrite = Writes.sqlDateWrites(myPattern)`

Then, when you create your `Writes` for whatever object you're converting:

```
case class Foo(id: Long, createdAt: java.sql.Date)

implicit val fooWrites: Writes[Foo] =  (
  (__ \ "id").write[Long] and
  (__ \ "createdAt").write[java.sql.Date](sqlDateWrite)
)(unlift(Foo.unapply))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! This is one way I could accomplish what I wanted, but I was hoping there was also a way to override the serialization for all timestamps outside the context of serializing case classes. So if I just called toJson(timestampObject) it would spit out a JsString.

Comment: I'm also not actually serializing case classes, my objects are Slick HLists, so I've been trying to stay away from the Combinator pattern and use the other method with the "def writes", but I don't think I can call the same .write[java.sql.Date] method in that format. Slick and Play JSON really do not seem to mix well at all.